# Signaling graceful shutdown to the pipeline

Tags: apache-beam

Im working with beam 2.3.0 at the moment. I've spent two days investigating how to gracefully shut down a pipline with the DirectRunner.
Setting blockOnRun to false and calling cancel just kills the pipeline and it is possible to lose data. I'm wondering if draining the pipeline first is possible before killing it like the dataflow runner does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature does not exist yet at the level of the Beam model. The only runner implementing something like this is Dataflow's Drain feature. There is a [proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NExwHlj-2q2WUGhSO4jTu8XGhDPmm3cllSN8IMmWci8/edit#heading=h.12g5c6ver98z) being discussed about making this a general Beam API.

Comment: Great info, thanks. Is there any roadmap or timeline for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a shutdown in our pipeline that reads from Kafka. I am not sure what your source is but as long that the source have some source of pause capability you could apply the same principles. Take a look at this [document](https://medium.com/doubleverify-engineering/how-to-gracefully-shut-down-a-spark-beam-pipeline-consuming-from-kafka-f6fe5776be40) in Medium.